# Why setInterval not working on production?

Tags: node.js, heroku, request

I want to run a function that makes a request to an API every certain amount of time but forever.

i am using Node.js to create it and it works on my machine but when i deploy it to heroku is not working. Any ideas?

```
var request = require('request');
var requestLoop = setInterval(function(){
  request({
      url: "https://holuserver.herokuapp.com/probando",
      method: "GET",
      timeout: 10000,
      followRedirect: true,
      maxRedirects: 10
  },function(error, response, body){
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
          console.log('sucess!');
      }else{
          console.log('error ' + response.statusCode);
      }
  });
}, 60000);
```